# Installing ASP.net on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to add ASP.net onto my Ununtu 20.04 server. As per:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

They tell you to:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Thats all good, apart from it gives a 404!

```
Resolving packages.microsoft.com (packages.microsoft.com)... 13.81.215.193
Connecting to packages.microsoft.com (packages.microsoft.com)|13.81.215.193|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-06-17 06:04:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Is there another way to do this? I've searched around, but can't find anything about the key being a 404. Thanks!

FWIW this is really weird! If you check out M$'s website:

https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/

You can see the file - but when you click on it, sure enough its a 404:

https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb

**UPDATE:** I found this page:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/linux-package-repository-for-microsoft-software

That got some of it working - but I now get:

```
root@south:/home/ebay# apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libauparse0 libc-ares2 nodejs-doc
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 aspnetcore-targeting-pack-3.1 dotnet-apphost-pack-3.1 dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-3.1 dotnet-runtime-3.1 dotnet-runtime-deps-3.1 dotnet-targeting-pack-3.1 netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 aspnetcore-targeting-pack-3.1 dotnet-apphost-pack-3.1 dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-3.1 dotnet-runtime-3.1 dotnet-runtime-deps-3.1 dotnet-sdk-3.1 dotnet-targeting-pack-3.1 netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 340 not upgraded.
Need to get 80.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 342 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 dotnet-host amd64 5.0.7-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
Err:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 dotnet-hostfxr-3.1 amd64 3.1.16-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
Err:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 dotnet-runtime-deps-3.1 amd64 3.1.16-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
Err:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 dotnet-runtime-3.1 amd64 3.1.16-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
Err:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 aspnetcore-runtime-3.1 amd64 3.1.16-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
Err:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 dotnet-targeting-pack-3.1 amd64 3.1.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
Err:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 aspnetcore-targeting-pack-3.1 amd64 3.1.10-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
Err:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 dotnet-apphost-pack-3.1 amd64 3.1.16-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
Err:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1 amd64 2.1.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
Err:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 dotnet-sdk-3.1 amd64 3.1.410-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/d/dotnet-host/dotnet-host-5.0.7-x64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/d/dotnet-hostfxr-3.1/dotnet-hostfxr-3.1.16-x64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/d/dotnet-runtime-deps-3.1/dotnet-runtime-deps-3.1.16-x64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/d/dotnet-runtime-3.1/dotnet-runtime-3.1.16-x64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/a/aspnetcore-runtime-3.1/aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.16-x64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/d/dotnet-targeting-pack-3.1/dotnet-targeting-pack-3.1.0-x64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/a/aspnetcore-targeting-pack-3.1/aspnetcore-targeting-pack-3.1.10.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/d/dotnet-apphost-pack-3.1/dotnet-apphost-pack-3.1.16-x64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/n/netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1/netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1_2.1.0-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod/pool/main/d/dotnet-sdk-3.1/dotnet-sdk-3.1.410-x64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 13.80.99.124 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**UPDATE:** M$ have fixed their repo, and it lets me install now!

Comment: Contact Microsoft and tell them to fix their URLs.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider any ideas on who to contact out of their millions of staff? :) Not sure what their official channel is

Comment: There is a button "Support" on their website. Personally, I'd probably start with their community forums.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider OMG I can't even find where to do that! I tried going through to https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/create , but once I had written up the whole question, it then tells me: "We were unable to find an eligible support plan associated with your account. Please add a support plan from the options below.". They want me to pay £200 for a one-off report, for their screw up :(

Comment: ok I posted here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/440043/404-for-packages-microsoft-proddeb-when-trying-to.html

Comment: @GeraldSchneider FYI, it seems like lots of others have also noticed it: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/24718 . Hopefully they fix it soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have now sorted this. Was an issue their end (and a lot of pretty miffed developers chasing them down)